# Python - Column in CSV file contains multiple delimiters and results

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have quite a large CSV file that has multiple columns (no delimiters) and one column which contains results that use three delimiters.

The main delimiter is ";", which separates days of results.

The second delimiter is ":", which separates results per day (I am only using 2 results out of a possible of 6).

The third delimiter is "/", which separates the result day and the calendar value of the result.

I want to avoid looping through the "X&Y" column as much as possible as the column itself contains many delimited results, and there are a lot of rows.

| Col1 | Col2 | X&Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 20200331/1D::::1:2;20200401/2D::::3:4;20200402/3D::::5:6 |
| AA | BB | 20210330/1Y::::11:22;20220330/2Y::::33:44;20230330/3Y::::55:66 |

I want to see:

| Col1 | Col2 | Date | CalendarValue | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 20200331 | 1D | 1 | 2 |
| A | B | 20200401 | 2D | 3 | 4 |
| A | B | 2020040 | 3D | 5 | 6 |
| AA | BB | 20210330 | 1Y | 11 | 22 |
| AA | BB | 20220330 | 2Y | 33 | 44 |
| AA | BB | 20220330 | 3Y | 55 | 66 |

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','AA'], 'Col2':['B', 'BB'], 'Col3':['20200331/1D::::1:2;20200401/2D::::3:4;20200402/3D::::5:6','20210330/1Y::::11:22;20220330/2Y::::33:44;20230330/3Y::::55:66']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out, split based on delimiter `(;)` followed by [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) to transform into rows. Followed by [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) & finally [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) the frames to get resultant frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'AA'], 'Col2': ['B', 'BB'],
                   'Col3': ['20200331/1D::::1:2;20200401/2D::::3:4;20200402/3D::::5:6',
                            '20210330/1Y::::11:22;20220330/2Y::::33:44;20230330/3Y::::55:66']})

df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].str.split(";")

# extract features from the string
extract_ = re.compile(r"(?P<Date>\w+)/(?P<CalendarValue>\w+):+(?P<X>.+):(?P<Y>.+)")

pd.concat([
    df.drop(columns='Col3'),
    df['Col3'].explode().str.extract(extract_, expand=True)
], axis=1)
```

---

```
Out[*]:

  Col1 Col2      Date CalendarValue   X   Y
0    A    B  20200331            1D   1   2
0    A    B  20200401            2D   3   4
0    A    B  20200402            3D   5   6
1   AA   BB  20210330            1Y  11  22
1   AA   BB  20220330            2Y  33  44
1   AA   BB  20230330            3Y  55  66
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/y0AjvT/1)

Comment: Hi sushanth, the result is perfect, however, I should of specified the "X&Y" values could be floating numbers, could you design a solution that can handle both integers and floating numbers?

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'AA'], 'Col2': ['B', 'BB'],
                   'Col3': ['20200331/1D::::1.2:2.2;20200401/2D::::3:4;20200402/3D::::5:6',
                            '20210330/1Y::::11.5:22;20220330/2Y::::33:44;20230330/3Y::::55:66']})

Comment: Hi sushanth, thank you again you have solved the problem I have asked for.

Again I have an issue with the calendar values, there sometimes contain hypen values and some calendar values that contain "/".

Could you solve it for both hyphen and non-hyphen calendar values

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','AA'], 'Col2':['B', 'BB'], 'Col3':['20200331/1D::::1.1:2.5;20200401/2D::::3:4;20200402/12M-15M::::-5.5:-6.56','20210330/O/N::::11.23:-22;20220330/JUN-21::::33:44;20230330/SEP-21::::-55.23:66']})

Comment: @FOS5252, SO is not a code writing service.. Please accept this post if it answers the question & for further queries please open a new question.